# Is this variant of Goormaghtigh's conjecture known?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, conjectures

Goormaghtigh's conjecture [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goormaghtigh_conjecture) that the only non-trivial integer solutions of

$$
{\frac {x^{m}-1}{x-1}}={\frac {y^{n}-1}{y-1}}
$$

satisfying

${\displaystyle x>y>1}$ and ${\displaystyle n,m>2}$ are

$$
{\displaystyle {\frac {5^{3}-1}{5-1}}={\frac {2^{5}-1}{2-1}}=31} 
$$

and

$$
{\displaystyle {\frac {90^{3}-1}{90-1}}={\frac {2^{13}-1}{2-1}}=8191.} 
$$
Now let $a$ and $b$ denote positive integers such that $a\neq b$ and $a,b>1$. Then there are many non-trivial integer solutions of

$$
a{\frac {x^{m}-1}{x-1}}=b{\frac {y^{n}-1}{y-1}},
$$

for comprime $x$ and $y$, albeit with the relaxed condition that $m,n>1$. For instance,

$$
84493{\frac {118352^{2}-1}{118352-1}}=39451{\frac {253478^{2}-1}{253478-1}}=10000000029.
$$

Is such a generalisation to Goormaghtigh's conjecture already known and studied in literature somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be infinitely many since $$a{\frac {x^{m}-1}{x-1}}=b{\frac {y^{n}-1}{y-1}}\implies\frac ab=\frac{(x-1)(y^n-1)}{(y-1)(x^m-1)}$$ is always a rational number for $a,b,x,y\in\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I think the point is to fix $a,b$ and ask about the solutions $x,y$. For example, will the set of nontrivial solutions be always finite?

Comment: My point is that you can always reverse engineer the process. For example, if let $m = 4$, $n = 5$, $x = 37$ and $y = 24$. Then you get values for $a$ and $b$ and this can be done for infinitely many values of $a,b$, and in turn, $x,y$.

Comment: That still doesn't answer the example question I have asked, but given that OP has accepted your question, I guess they are satisfied with this answer